# Should I eat the possibly-rotten pizza?

Tags: the-gold-factory

After digging the hole further, I found a pile of pizza. The game warns me it might be rotten.

I get the choice to either eat the pizza or leave it alone - what impact does it have, and is the pizza really rotten?

Comment: Good kids never should do this...

Comment: How do you dig the hole further?

Comment: @boo That's a great question to ask on the site, you know. (TL;DR: There's a clickable field on the right side of the hole that goes 2/3 ways through with multiple sections before it comes to a stop where "future updates could go")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is, quite literally a **50% chance** of the pizza being rotten.

On success of that random event, the following message appears and a random amount (between 10 and 50) pizzas is eaten:

> **Nom.. nom..**
>   You eat the pizzas, luckily they are not rotten

On failure, you are poisoned, giving various negative effects throughout the game. The poison can be removed, as per the message that appears:

> **Nom.. nom..**
>   You eat the pizzas, but... they are rotten!
>   You are poisoned, this causes you to die easily in battles even if you have a lot of hp
>   Luckily you can heal yourself by drinking 10 health potions [Drink 10 health potions]