# How do I get cookies?

Tags: the-gold-factory

Many potion recipes include cookies as an ingredient, but I have progressed quite far in the game but not found out where they come from.

Where do I get cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging deep, you'll find the Cookie Clicker game where you can bake cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie clicker game is behind the / in the tunnel that you can dig to the right of the training facility.  The start of the tunnel is above the training facility and to the right.

> ____/____

[Post with this map:](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/167893/51171)

[image: Map of The Gold Factory before the Nether appears]

From left to right, the tunnel has

1. The name tag changing place.
2. A chest (contains the ancient scroll that explains how to use the nether stones from the [castle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/167893/51171)).
3. The pile of ([possibly rotten](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/146360/51171)) pizzas.
4. The cookie clicker place.
5. An old machine.  Converts powers of 10 numbers of gold bars to a tenth that number of iron bars.  Uses the [lava bucket](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/146524/51171).
6. A sign saying that this is the end of the tunnel.  No more to dig.