# What is the lava bucket used for?

Tags: the-gold-factory

Once you beat the Nether you receive a Lava Bucket. It has no use apparently. It is used lately? Can I get more beating the Nether again? Can I try to mix it to make potions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a updated version you use the lava bucket to fix a machine past the cookie clicker in the hole you dug that turns gold bars into iron bars.

Comment: You can get multiple lava buckets from the nether while that machine uses 1.  Is there a place for the additional ones you can get?