# Life beyond the castle?

Tags: the-gold-factory

I've completed the Castle of Zombies (several times), done all the boss ciphers, beat the training robot (several times), and dug to the Old Machine that needs a lava bucket.  I also have Diamond Sword, Helmet, and Boots (working on Diamond Chestplate and Pants).

Where can I go from here?  What lies beyond the Castle of Zombies and how do I get there?

Here is my map, currently:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The next step is to buy the airplane, which is next to the castle to the right. With it you can fly to the clouds.

You finish the castle to get the nether stones, and mixing them with the scroll it will make appear the Nether and the plane.

Comment: I can't find anything by the castle.

Comment: Looking through the code, I am apparently missing the ancient scroll.  I've opened all the chests but still do not have it?

Comment: If you got the Nether Rock you should get the Ancient Scroll in the chest guarded by the ghost

Comment: Something must have glitched.  I just gave myself the scroll item and the lab, portal, and plane showed up.

Answer (score 0):

The lab for making potions appears later after whatever glitch occurred wears off.
There is also a plane to reach an invisible castle, a portal, and multiple mini quests in the portal world.